# Can I get around creating a database by constantly writing over a saved file? beginner question

Tags: java, database, file, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I just coded this program that has a form as its user interface, where someone can enter in data. The program then takes that data and enters it into a saved excel file using apache POI.

My question is, if I want to send out this program to other people on other computers, do I need to code a database? I thought I wouldn't have to if I coded it such that every time data is submitted through the form, the form takes the excel file as it currently is, puts in new information, and then re-saves the now updated excel file to the same variable on the File class. It works perfectly on my computer, but I want to know in advance if it will work on multiple computers.

If what I did is incorrect, is the only alternative to code a database? I've never done it before and it seems a little daunting. Do you have any suggestions on where I should start? thanks.

Here is the relevant code if anyone is interested. I have my constructor where I assign a variable to the file that is saved directly in the Java program (called UI), and then an addToExcel method that locates the right cells and adds the data. Focus on the beginning and end of the addToExcel method where I open the file and then save/close it and re-save it to the variable of the File class.

```
  public TradingExcel() throws IOException {
    excelFile = new File("Excels/tradingExcel.xlsx");
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFile);

    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); }


public void addToExcel(InternData internData) throws IOException {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(this.excelFile);

    String[] rawName = internData.getName().split(" ");
    String firstName = rawName[0];
    String lastName = rawName[1];

    for(int i = 0; i <= this.workbook.getSheetAt(0).getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        if ((this.workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(0)).toString().equals(firstName) &&
                (this.workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(1)).toString().equals(lastName)) {

            int lastCellNum = this.workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getLastCellNum();

            XSSFCell NPL = this.workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).createCell(lastCellNum);
            NPL.setCellValue(internData.getNpl());
            XSSFCell LPL = this.workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).createCell(lastCellNum+1);
            LPL.setCellValue(internData.getLpl());
            XSSFCell Shares = this.workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).createCell(lastCellNum+2);
            Shares.setCellValue(internData.getShares());
        }
        else {}
    }

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(this.excelFile);
    this.workbook.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();

    excelFile = new File("Excels/tradingExcel.xlsx");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You rarely have to code a database, because there are many available freely.

Answer (score 2):

For others to use locally your current approach is fine.

I would strongly suggest you make your save-to-file code very robust against errors.  Write to a temporary file and only rename the current one to be the backup file when that successful and only rename the temporary file to the current name when the backup rename is successful.  Too many have lost work when they didn’t have to.

If multiple users can work on the same file you need to be even more careful. File locking and those kinds of things.

Comment: What do you mean by for others to use locally? If I create an .exe of my program and let others download it, will it still work? That's what I aim to do with the program, but that doesn't really sound like it's local. Thanks for the tips though

Comment: “Local” means on the same machine using the same file   Not typically the case for windows users.

Comment: I hope I dont sound annoying, but I'm still confused. Are you saying my current approach will not work as I want it to, where users can input their data into the same excel from their own computer?

Comment: @Lord Skarpo: You need to clarify what your application does.  Does each user have their own private copy of an excel file or do all the users share one and only one excel file?

Comment: each user shares one and only one excel file. sorry if that wasn't clear. I want everyone's data to be inputted to the same, existing excel spreadsheet. I've already coded it, just don't know how to allow the same excel spreadsheet to exist in different downloads of my .exe

Comment: "how to allow the same excel spreadsheet to exist in different downloads of my .exe"?  Eh, across machines?  No, use a database behind a webapplication.

Comment: But I can also use a database behind a java .exe, correct? I've been trying to learn how to create a database and I feel very stuck, so I'm wondering if there's anything else I could do, like for example coding in a way to send the data inputted into the gui back to my computer automatically. Have you ever heard of such a thing?

Comment: Yes, you can talk to a database from a Java program.  The technology is called JDBC, and I strongly suggest following the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html trail in the Oracle tutorial.  Note that you will need to learn SQL to talk to a database - any other way is just hiding this from you.

Answer (score 1):

As you ask this as a "beginner question", the short answer is: No, it is not possible to avoid database usage by constantly writing over a saved file.

Problems with constantly writing over a saved file:

As long as you are the only user of this file, it may work but always leads to the danger to destroy the fie if something wrong occurs while writing process (mainly as long as the `FileOutputStream` stays open). And if such error occurs and if the file is the only storage for the data, then the data is lost.

If multiple users are using their own file each, then it also may work. But see above. But then you have n versions of the file for n users and that leads to the question how to merge together the data in all of those n files. This is not really a simple task for `Excel` files.

If multiple users shall share the same file, then first question will be where to store the file so that all users can access it. This could be solved: web-server, shared folder,  ...

But other problems comes on. If user one opens the file to input data and user two also opens the file a short time later and before user one has saved, then it is obvious that either the input of user one or the input of user two gets lost. If user one saves first and then user two saves, then saving of user two overwrites input of user one. The same vice versa. If both try saving the same time one will fail and possibly crash the whole file.

One solution for this problem is locking the file if a user opens it. But that means that user two cannot open the file to input data until user one has saved and the lock is released. So user two must wait.

Another solution is to have a manager software which serves the file to multiple users, gets their saved results and merges those results together in the file. This is what a share-point server does. But there also a database is used in background.

The benefit of a database is that it provides `UPDATE` statements which update single field values in single rows and `INSERT` statements which insert single rows with field values. For concurrent usage those `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statements need locking the table only as long as they are running. And the database management software manages it so that multiple users can make updates or inserts and the software takes care on the sequence and the locking/unlocking.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It sounds like I need a database. Using the update or insert statements I can create methods that input data into a table, form where I can easily read data and input it into the excel. Do you have any suggestions on what database I should use, or how I should stucture it?

Comment: @Lord Skarpo: Any kind of customary  database management software will work. The first need is a server which provides access to multiple users. As you are a beginner I would not recommend a self administered server. So choose rent a place on a managed web server. Most of those come with a database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, or others) already.

Comment: I think if I use a simpler database language like h2 it will be manageable, as h2 is embedded in java. I don't need the database to be external or anything, really a text file is enough as long as multiple users can access it and it saves all data. I'm not looking to rent a server.